# Jupyter/Ipython Notebook: How to time multiline segment of code?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, timing

The [`%time` magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html) allows you to conveniently time a single line of Python code.

Can I also time a block of code without wrapping it in a function first? Is there an equivalent function that times an entire cell?

Comment: I guess we should use %time on all the lines we want to time and add them up manually :P. Even I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cell magics starts with `%%` while line magics starts with `%`.

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions

Comment: But I guess this doesn't work if I use it in jupyter notebook using pyspark kernel?

Comment: @Baktaawar inline %time magic doesn't work as well with PySpark kernel

Comment: Adding to this answer: make sure to put `%%time` on the first line and then your commands on the following lines in the cell.